# error while installing open-mpi (make : No rule to make target 'all' stop)

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-12.04, openmpi

I am trying to install open-mpi library on Ubuntu 
I downloaded it from www.open-mpi.org
I followed instructions to install it as follows

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/openmpi

make all
make install
```

when i get to make all command it gives the following error

```
make :***  No rule to make target 'all' Stop
```

I don't know what can cause such an error

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to that the error was in configuration there were no g++ and gfortran compilers 
so you have either to install them using 
sudo apt-get install g++ gfortran

### or disable them

i have now another problem when i try to compile the code it gives me the following error

Can't open module file 'mpi.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory

does anyone knows the answer?

Comment: New questions should be asked separately. You won't get anyone to answer a question inside an answer.